# How to sort the values in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to sort the values but not getting the desirable result. Can you please help me how to do this?

Example:

```
df = pd.read_csv("D:/Users/SPate233/Downloads/iMedical/sqoop/New folder/metadata_file_imedical.txt", delimiter='~')
#df.sort_values(by = ['dependency'], inplace = True)
df.sort_values('dependency', ascending=True, inplace=True)
print(list(df['dependency'].unique()))
```

Output:

```
['0', '1', '1,10,11,26,28,55', '1,26,28', '10', '11', '12', '17,42', '2', '26,28', '33', '42', '6']
```

Desirable_output:

```
['0', '1', '2', '6', '10', '11', '12', '33', '42', '17,42', '26,28', '1,26,28', '1,10,11,26,28,55']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Order by the length of the string, and then by its value:

```
df.assign(len = df.dependency.str.len()).sort_values(["len", "dependency"])
```

The output is (leaving the `len` column in for clarity):

```
          dependency  len
0                  0    1
1                  1    1
8                  2    1
12                 6    1
4                 10    2
5                 11    2
6                 12    2
10                33    2
11                42    2
7              17,42    5
9              26,28    5
3            1,26,28    7
2   1,10,11,26,28,55   16
```